# Winforms vs winapi

Tags: winapi, winforms, c++

У меня старая ОС(windows xp) и компилятор(mvs 2010) на данный момент доступны только две технологии писать свои форточки winforms и голый winapi, какую технологию лучше выбрать после консольных приложений?

Comment: а вам для чего вообще?

Comment: для общего развития. ибо консольные приложения из задачника решаю уже как орешки.

Comment: Хотите выучить востребованную платформу? Поставьте нормальную ОС (по крайней мере Window 7), Visual Studio 2010 вполне подойдёт. Сразу переходите на C#.

Если комп не тянет новую ОС, потратьте деньги на новый комп. Это вложение отобьётся с первой зарплаты, в крайнем случае со второй.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если для общего развития и речь именно о развитии в рамках С++, то, пожалуй, я бы предпочел WInAPI - там  хотя бы именно С++ используется, в отличие от WInForms, где, насколько я знаю, задействован С++/CLI. Хотя на мой взгляд, и то  и другое - не самое лучшее приложение сил.

Если же вы планируете связать с какой-то из этих технологий дальнейшую профессиональную деятельность и тем самым зарабатывать, то я бы не советовал связываться ни с тем ни с другим - для создания оконных приложений под Win есть куда более адекватные альтернативы, се-таки на дворе XXI век как-никак.

Comment: все понял спасибо

Comment: WInAPI - это чистый С, никакого С++. Для понимания событийного программирования и внутренностей оконных приложений, на мой взгляд самое то. 
WinForms - это С++ + MFC + GDI+ + OLE + ... . Тоже небесполезное занятие для умения разбираться в разнообразном API и наметать руку на рисовании в окнах и добавлении разнородного мультимедийного контента.
WPF - это С++\CLI или С#. Да - с ним намного приятнее работать. Но без знания основ, я считаю, там будет не так весело.
Так что, моё мнение - надо попробовать все технологии снизу вверх! Писать на WinAPI тяжело, конечно, но наиболее весело.